# Tkinter python append lines in separate file

Tags: python, tkinter

I have no formal programming experience so please forgive my lack of terminology and program structure. Stackoverflow has been a tremendous help. This is my first question so please be gentle.

I have been tasked with writing a GUI. As of now, I works well and I have over 3500 lines of code and multiple files..

I need the Append lines in a separate file if someone could please give me some guidance. Please let me know if my question is not clear enough. Thank you.  (Python 2.7.x & Tkinter)

(this does not work for obvious reasons I just can't quite get my head around the class part)

*save_test.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.createWidgets()
    self.DoIt()

   def createWidgets(self):
       self.code = []

       # Create Frames
       self.FileFrame = Frame(self, bd=5)
       self.FileFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, sticky=N + S + E + W)

       self.f10 = Label(self.FileFrame, text='Enter Number', width=15, font="-weight bold")
       self.f10.grid(row=0, column=0)

       self.entersomething = StringVar()
       self.entersomething.set("123")
       self.es = Entry(self.FileFrame, textvariable=self.entersomething, width=5)
       self.es.grid(row=0, column=1)


       self.Send = Button(self.FileFrame, text='Send To File', command=self.SendButton)
       self.Send.grid(row=0, column=2,)


   def SendButton(self):
       self.DoIt()
       f = open('c:\Python\code.txt', 'w')
       for line in self.code:
           f.write(line + '\n')
       f.close()

   def DoIt(self):

       thickness = float(self.es.get())

       self.code = []

       #something here to make it append the lines in mycode.py

app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

*mycode.py*

```
self.code.append('(Code Generated)')
self.code.append('#1=%.4f (Thickness)' % thickness)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make one small change: Open the file with the 'a' flag, for append:

```
 f = open('c:\Python\code.txt', 'a')
```

Comment: Thank you but I reworded the question. Hopefully it is a little more clear now.